# Tool/Method to resolve trait associated types

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types

I have some rust code containing trait associated types. I need a way to resolve these associated types into their real types where they are being used. In other words, I need to have a way (could be any external tool) to convert rust code like:

```rust
trait T {
    type AssociatedType;
}

struct S;
impl T for S {
    type AssociatedType = u32;
}

struct R {
    m: <S as T>::AssociatedType,
}

fn function() {
    let _: <S as T>::AssociatedType = <S as T>::AssociatedType::Default();
}
```

to rust code where the trait associated types are replaced with their actual type. So every line with

```rust
<S as T>::AssociatedType
```

is replaced with

```rust
u32
```

and that for all trait associated types of course.
Do I need to look at parsing the rmeta files produced by the compiler? Can the RLS provide me with a solution here?

Why do I want this? I have some procedural macros that generate some extern C functions and structs that I like to expose using cbindgen. However, cbindgen can't handle those trait associated types and will produce a header containing `AssociatedType` as the type instead of its actual type. The issue has been reported to cbindgen (https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/issues/106) but
the author clearly indicated that, since it doesn't hook into the rust compiler, this will not be fixed soon (if at all). Now I don't care what tool needs to be called, as long as this can be automated.

Looking at what RLS can 'solve', using the rust-analyser plugin for visual code, I got this:
[image: code completion via RLS for struct member]
[image: code completion via RLS for variable]

So it seems to be able to resolve it for the variable, but not for the struct member type - where I need it most.

Comment: i think you can do it with proc macros.

Comment: could you elaborate on that?